# Client Authentication through Encryption using a master key?

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption

Is this a common and well-regarded pattern?

Secondary Question: Best encryption standard for my context?

Context: I have a windows service which sends JSON data to a RESTFul Service. In that JSON Payload is authentication credentials (passhash and username), but I still must account for a registered user tampering with the other "data driven" parts of the payload.

My Solution: Encrypt the payload with a private/master key from within the source code, obfuscated the best I can. This will verify the client (unless the master key is broken).

EDIT: My service collects internet latency data. I do not want to collect hand-edited data values. I realize that with the volatile/everchanging nature of network performance/latency, a user could simply unplug their connection or bunker down theirs to the point that my client is not given enough bandwidth/resources to do it job. These are things that I cannot realistically account for with the knowledge and time that I have. However, I do think I can protect service from receiving hand-edited payloads.

Comment: Some thing you need to ask yourself, who are you protecting the data from? It greatly affects how you implment the solution. Can you edit your question and add a paragraph explaining why you need to add your own encryption (beyond say, a SSL connection) and what your threat model is?

Comment: I gave it my best shot... This is my first time really delving into security through a developer side, so let me know if you have any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I want to do is clarify something in your expectations.

There are 2 aspects to the data that are important to you:

- **Authentication** - The data that was sent to you was sent from a authorized, unmodified, program
- **Integrity** - The Data that was sent to you was not modified in transit.

The Integrity problem is the easier one to solve, simply have your program use a SSL connection to the server. You don't even need to use a cert signed by one of the normal CA's, in fact it may be better that you don't! You could create a CA for your App, then sign the cert yourself that will be running on the webserver with that private CA. If you do that you can hard code the public key of your CA in to the program and only allow it to connect to servers who have certificates signed by your private CA. Doing this will help prevent someone setting up a MITM SSL Proxy (for example [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)) to edit the data while it is being transmitted.

Authentication is a bit of a harder problem to solve. You need to prevent fake clients or modified real clients from connecting to your server and sending fake data, and that is not a easy problem to solve. If your software is running on a device where the ***attacker*** can run arbitrary code, the problem is **impossible to solve**. The reason it is impossible is the user could attach a debugger and step through your code step by step and replicate your process. The the only way to "solve" it is running your program on something that does not allow the user to run anything and any software that does run must be vetted by a 3rd party first (like a un-jailbroken phone).

However you can "mitigate" the problem, you don't need to make it impossible, just hard enough that any malicious user would not find it worth the effort to overcome the obstacles you put in.

Some things you can do to make it harder on a an attacker:

- All message are signed using a secret key you do your damndest to hide.
- Use a code obfuscator on the code to make it harder to reverse engineer.
- Use client certificates in your SSL connection and have your server reject any connection that does not have them.
- Higher a consultant who is more experienced than you to make your code harder to reverse engineer.

There is much much more that can be done but that is what I came up with with just thinking for a few minutes.

So to boil this all down, if you are not too concerned, just use bog standard SSL, that will likely stop 75% of the tampering. If you are more concerned, use the custom CA trick to foil any SSL MITM attacks to maybe get you up to 80%. But if you want to get above that 80%, it gets exponentially harder to do, and at some point you need to stop and ask your self "***Is the amount of time/effort/money I am putting in to stopping that one more person from sending me that bad data worth it? Or can I just live with 20 out of 100 people sending me bad data, what about 10, 5, 1?***"

Comment: Thank you for your well constructed reply. I was just going to subscribe to Positive SSL for over the write (non-custom certificate, I suppose) to prevent tampering over wire (although I'm not too sure if a MITM SSL attack would be effective if the JSON payload was encrypted (by AES, etc) before the SSL encryption already took place).

I will just try to obfuscate the hell out of it (the master key). My  main concern was having the ISP's I am trying to force to improve making false data to portray "high quality" service.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thats why I said it is important to figure out who the attacker is. I wrote up my answer thinking you are trying to stop the end user from modifying the data. if you are trying to check if the end users's ISP is modifying the data that is super easy. Just normal, no frills SSL will do that, unless the isp is forging certificates (and if you have proof of them doing that I bet you a few reporters would pay good money for that info) just plain old SSL will prevent all tampering. That's (one of) the reason it was invented.

Comment: The ISP has no access to the sofware running on the end user's computer, so you don't need to worry about the software "defending itself" from attacks. With the threat model of a 3rd party trying to tamper with the data you just need make sure you have a valid secure channel to your server and everything is good to go. No code obfuscation required.

Comment: I made once change to the post to maybe help make it more clear: "*If your software is running on a device where the **attacker** can run arbitrary code, the problem is impossible to solve*" The ISP can not run arbitrary code on the users computer, so you don't need to worry about 90% of the stuff I was talking about.

Comment: What if the ISP decides to become a user (my client will be publicly available and anyone can sign up (with a verified email address), and as long as their external ip's hostname validates to be on the ISP's domain, my server will accept their data (with verified credientals) at a limit of one "report" every 30 minutes per IP/User.

Comment: Ok, so I ask you: Is 1 user for maybe every 2000 real reporting users a problem? Throw out the top 5% best scores (the ISP's cheating to look good) and the bottom 5% worst scores (the users cheating trying to "stick it" to their ISP) and the law of averages should get you a fairly accurate score.

Comment: So I should just use SSL and throw out any sort of client authenication (besides user/pass-hash)?

Comment: For your threat model, as described, yea. However I would not trust the advice of someone on the internet who does not have all the facts. Continue to educate your self, try to learn more about how to do secruity *correctly* and make your own conclusions after you analise the "facts" of the situation, not just do what you "feel" you should do, or what "you have heard everyone else does to be secure". I  highly recommend the http://security.stackexchange.com/ site. Take a look and you will learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If the RESTFul service is your own, you could enable windows authentication on it (or deploy another instance of it with windows auth) and then authenticate the user, preferably that they belong to a role (or group). That way you've got no certificates or keys to mess with and it's secure.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case. This is a wide variety of client windows machines and a google app engine server-end.

Comment: That's a shame! Oh well, I'll leave this answer as it is because it might be helpful for someone in the future.