# Using a Common Private Key for Digital Signatures

Tags: asp.net, encryption, cryptography

I have a mobile application and a server. The mobile application communicates with the server through a web services framework via SSL.

The mobile application allows customers to pay for transactions. The server authenticates the mobile application on every web service call via a username, password, device id and digital signature.

The device id ensures that the mobile account is being accessed from the device that was used to create the account. Therefore, a hacker requires physical access to the smartphone, even if he knows the username and password of a mobile account.

The digital signature is computed using a private key which is hard-coded inside the mobile application. Every message sent from the mobile application is accompanied with a digital signature computed using this private key. This ensures that the message is coming from the mobile application and that the contents of the message were not altered while in transit.

What would be the consequences if this private key was discovered? Will a hacker be able to modify information that is being transmitted via SSL and still recompute a valid digital signature using this private key? Would it be better if the mobile application generates a public-private key pair and send the public key to the server, or would this be unneccessary? Thank you so much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a security scheme, not programming in itself. Try security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacker can always forge fake requests for his account from his phone to your server, if a hacker as unrestricted access to the device there is no way in stopping that.

However one thing that a hacker could also do if all phones shared the same key for signing is fake a request for another phone he does not have access to if he knows the other phone's device ID.

The simple way to solve this issue is each phone has it's own key for authenticating that is generated at the time of install for it's messages.

You may already be doing this, but you did not really say in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  If I turn the WSDL documentation protocol off, do you think that the scenario described in the second paragraph can occur?  If the WDSL documentation protocol is off, new applications won't be able to discover the web service.  However, compiled applications can still use it.

Comment: Or is it possible for the hacker to modify the mobile application and hard-code another device id?

Comment: @Matthew disabling the documentation won't stop it, a hacker can just look a the code in your app to find out what endpoints are available. For your 2nd question, I am assuming the device id is a piece of "public" information that a hacker could get about another phone without access to the phone itself. That is why each device needs a separate unique key for signing, so the only way a hacker could know the key he would need physical access to the device and, as I said, there is no way to stop a hacker from forging messages that appear to come from a device he has physical access to.

Comment: Also note, there is a very big difference between "stop" and "make hard enough to do that it is more effort than it is worth to do it". You need to evaluate your threat model and find out which of those to options you really need. And if you choose the second how "hard" is your bar for "hard enough"?

Comment: I highly recommend you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875885/client-authentication-through-encryption-using-a-master-key) and the answer I gave to it for some more details talking about "hard enough" protection.

Comment: Thank you for your response Scott. I appreciate it immensely.